# Menu WordPress com opção de páginas e categoria

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou aprendendo a fazer temas de WordPress e vendo tutoriais como fazer a chamada de menus no Wordpress.

Vi vários tutoriais de como chamar menu de categoria e de páginas, mas não estou achando um tutorial de como criar um menu que chame os dois, pois vejo muitos sites que dispõem desta opção.

Existe algum tutorial de como fazer isso? Estou iniciando na construção de temas, mas já administro há algum tempo sites de WordPress.

Comment: Melhor que pedir sugestões de tutoriais -o Google é especialista nisso- é mostrar seu código e qual seu problema com ele. A especialidade deste site são programadores resolvendo problemas de programação.

Comment: Já resolvi, esta tudo ok. Vou postar depois aqui o código.

Answer (score 1):

A melhor forma de trabalhar com menus em temas WordPress é utilizando a função nativa, a tempos não é mais necessário utilizar funções do tipo

> wp_list_categories()

para os menus, então vamos lá.

Primeiro você precisa habilitar o suporte à menus no seu tema, para isso insira o código abaixo no functions.php do seu tema:

> if (function_exists('add_theme_support')) {
>       add_theme_support('topo');
>       add_theme_support('rodape'); }

Feito isso no seu tema você vai usar os códigos abaixo para exibir os menus onde desejar:

```
wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'topo' ) );
wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'rodape' ) );
```

Agora é só acessar o menu Aparência > Menus na página administrativa do seu tema, clicar em criar novo menu, ai você vai selecionar topo ou rodapé e escolher quais páginas e categorias devem fazer parte do menu. Na pratica é bem simples.

Answer (score 1):

Obrigado Leo, vou estudar este método tbm.

Eu vi no codex desta forma

no functions botei assim:

```
if ( function_exists( 'register_nav_menus' ) ) {
register_nav_menus(
array(
'header-menu' => 'top menu',
)
);
}
```

e nas paginas assim.

```
<nav id="menu">
        <?php
        wp_nav_menu(array(
        'theme_location' => 'header-menu', // aqi vc seleciona o menu que vc registrou
        'container' => 'nav',
        'container_id' => 'nav',
        'container_class' => 'nav-teste',
        'menu_id' => 'menu',
        'menu_class' => 'menu',
        'echo' => true,
        'before' => '',
        'after' => '',
        'link_before' => '',
        'link_after' => '',
        'depth' => '0',
        ));
        ?>
    </nav>
```

Obrigado.